# Can I link my local MYSQL tables with XAMPP?

Tags: mysql

I have created some tables locally on MySQL 5.7 . I want my front end to send data to these tables and I am using XAMPP . Can I link both of them or do I have to create a separate database and tables on PHPMYADMIN ? I am using Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the path directory data to your new path like this :

> Take care of this operation because, you change all the settings
>   authentication and your new data MUST be the **same "version"** and you need
>   to use the passwords of you new database users.

If you are on **windows** :

> copy backup the file C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

Go **C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini** and open your **my.ini** and *search* **CTRL + F** : **datadir**

```
;Path to data directory C:/xampp/../mysqlX.X.XX/data
datadir="K:/MYSQL_SERVER/../../mysqlX.X.XX/data"
```

On linux : you need to **chown** the mysql folder to mysql user group **mysql:mysql**

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /home/to/MYSQL5.7/data/
```

Change the setting of MYSQL :

> Go copy/backup and open to edit /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/your/new/data/dir
```

Save and restart MYSQLD

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
```

Comment: I couldn't understand . Can you explain in simpler steps ? I think I will have to first make my local database import-ready.

Comment: @Varad Bhatnagar hi can you tell wich OS, and path where your xampp was installed i can make a step by step but it depend on your OS version. MYSQL got a file configuration named MY.INI where you can find the line datadir change the path to your new path of your new MYSQL DATA wanted to load by the server as new DATABASES.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
I used the mysqldump command to create a dump of my database in the home directory first.

After this , I just chose same file under the import database option on PHPMYADMIN.